# Why does Retrieving Data from Firebase Realtime Database and then setting textView text to that value in android cause app crash?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I watched a bunch of firebase tutorials and tried to replicate what they did, but doing so causes in an app crash. I tried looking up the issue and tried to try what other people did, but alas none of it worked.

Here is my code

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    points = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.points);
    rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
   rootReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                UserInformation uInfo = new UserInformation();
               pointsString = ds.child("users").child(uid).child("points").getValue().toString();
            }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
   points.setText(pointsString);

   // points.setText(uid);
    return v;



}
```

I tried to make sure the textView was setup right by doing setText() with a random word and it worked, so it's something with firebase. Here is the log cat

```
04-03 23:24:03.529 5655-5655/com.example.dadei.quizler E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.dadei.quizler, PID: 5655
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
    at com.example.dadei.quizler.HomeFragment$2.onDataChange(HomeFragment.java:78)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzejp.zza(Unknown Source:13)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelk.zza(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzelq.run(Unknown Source:71)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

04-03 23:24:03.537 5655-5655/com.example.dadei.quizler I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 5655 SIG: 9

EDIT: Edit: It wasn't working because I didn't store the value as a string in the sign up class, so it returned a null reference. When I changed setValue(0) to setValue(0).toString();. It worked. Hopefully this may help someone else with the same issue.

Comment: If you app crashed, there is an error message and a stack trace in your logcat output. Please find those and add them to your question to improve the chance that someone may be able to help.

Comment: https://ideone.com/PPHi95 onDataChange = 2 and setText = 3 ... **edit:** but TextView.setText(null) should not cause the problem ... so error is not here(but even if you will fix it - code will not work as you expected)

Answer (score 0):

Edit: It wasn't working because I didn't store the value as a string in the sign up class, so it returned a null reference. When I changed setValue(0) to setValue(0).toString();. It worked. Hopefully this may help someone else with the same issue.